# Geoserver result of query done in SQL View is not complete

Tags: geoserver, deck.gl, vector-tiles, mvt

I'm new to  Geoserver and I'm trying to do  a visualisation application with MVT, to  achieve that I use MobilityDB which is an extension to the PostgreSQL database system and its spatial extension PostGIS. It allows temporal and spatio-temporal objects to be stored in the database, that is, objects whose attribute values and/or location evolves in time. I actually use a function that given a trip (which  is an array of point with their timestamps) and the index of a tile I get all the point in the trip that go through this tile as a LINESTRING in  tile coordinates and the timestamps of those points.

So I have a table with  2  columns one is a geometry  in  tile coordinates and the second one is an  array of bigint(timestamps in unix epoch)

What  I have done is creating the SQL View on Geoserver and put this query  in

```
WITH bounds AS (
        SELECT ST_TileEnvelope(14,8389,5497) AS geom
    ),
    val AS (
        SELECT asMVTGeom(trip, (bounds.geom)::stbox) as geom_times
        FROM trips, bounds
    ),
    mvtgeom AS(
        SELECT  (geom_times).geom, (geom_times).times
        FROM val
    )


select  mvtgeom.geom, mvtgeom.times from  mvtgeom where mvtgeom.geom is not null;
```

the first column is either a LINESTRING or  MULTILIINESTRING and i convert the second column to  text so it can be read by  geoserver.

The problem  here is that i the query  return for example 500 rows I only get 135 elements in my response from geoserver sometime even if the query has a result I get 0 elements.

In my client application I run this code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import axios from  "axios";
import FPSStats from "react-fps-stats";
import {MVTLoader} from '@loaders.gl/mvt';
import {load} from '@loaders.gl/core';
import {MVTLayer, TripsLayer, TileLayer} from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';
import {StaticMap} from "react-map-gl";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const MAP_STYLE = 'https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/positron-nolabels-gl-style/style.json';

const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
    //berlin
    longitude: 4.4,
    latitude: 50.85,
    zoom: 11,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 23
};

// animation start and end in unix timestamp
const min_timestamp = 1180324800;
const max_timestamp = 1180339200;

function useQuery() {
    return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

export default function App({
                                trailLength = 180,
                                loopLength = max_timestamp-min_timestamp,
                                animationSpeed = 5
                            }) {


    const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
    const [animation] = useState({});

    const animate = () => {
        setTime(t => (t + animationSpeed) % loopLength);
        animation.id = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    };

    const toTimestamp = (strDate) => {
        const dt = Date.parse(strDate);
        return dt / 1000;
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            animation.id = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            return () => window.cancelAnimationFrame(animation.id);
        },
        [animation]
    );

    const onTileLoad = (tile) => {
        console.log("=============================");
        console.log("Tile coord",tile.id);
        console.log("The content  is ",tile)
        console.log("==============================");

        if(tile.content.length > 0) {
            //console.log(tile);
        }

        const features = [];
        if (tile.content.byteLength > 0 ){
            for (const feature of tile.dataInWGS84) {
                const ts = feature.properties.times;
                const ts_final = ts.substring(1, ts.length - 1).split(",").map(t => parseInt(t, 10));

                if (feature.geometry.type === "MultiLineString") {
                    let index = 0;
                    for (const coords of feature.geometry.coordinates) {
                        const ts_segment = ts_final.slice(index, index + coords.length)
                        features.push({
                            ...feature,
                            geometry: {type: "LineString", coordinates: coords},
                            properties: {times: ts_segment}
                        });
                        index = coords.length;
                    }
                } else {
                    features.push({...feature, properties: {times: ts_final}});
                }
            }
            console.log("Features ",features)

            tile.content = features;
        }

    }

    const data = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&" +
        "layers=PostGIS:blabla&bbox=-180,-90,180,90&width=1024&" +
        "height=1024&format=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&crs=EPSG:3857&" +
        "viewparams=z:{z};x:{x};y:{y}";


    const layer = new MVTLayer({
        id: 'trips',
        data,
        loader : MVTLoader,
        loadOptions : {
            coordinates: "wgs84"
        },
        binary : false,
        onTileLoad : onTileLoad,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 23,
        lineWidthMinPixels: 1,
        currentTime : 15900000,
        /*
        renderSubLayers: props => {

            return new TripsLayer(props, {
                data: props.data,
                getPath: d => d.geometry.coordinates,
                getTimestamps : d => d.properties.times,
                opacity: 0.5,
                widthMinPixels: 2,
                rounded: true,
                trailLength,
            });
        }

         */
    })

    return (
        <DeckGL
            layers={[layer]}
            initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
            controller={true}
        >
            <StaticMap mapStyle={MAP_STYLE} />
        </DeckGL>
    );
}

export function renderToDOM(container) {
    render(<Router><App /><FPSStats /></Router>, container);
}
```

I use this request  but I don't know if  when  I use the application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile the geometry  should already  be in tile coordinates or not.

Thank you in advance for your help  don't hesitate ask  if you  need more details. It is the first time I  do  such  a request